# Pandas: Dangerous to align on float columns for join?

Tags: pandas

Consider the following:

```
>>> a = pd.read_csv('x', keep_default_na=False)
>>> a
   id    val type
0   0  5.812     
1   1  5.232     
2   2  5.342     
3   3  5.443     

>>> b = pd.read_csv('y', keep_default_na=False)
>>> b
   id    val type
0   0  5.812    a
1   1  5.232    b
2   2  5.342    c
3   3  5.443    d

>>> a.set_index(['id','val']).drop('type',axis=1).join(b.set_index(['id', 'val'])).reset_index()
   id    val type
0   0  5.812    a
1   1  5.232    b
2   2  5.342  NaN   <------ Not c!
3   3  5.443    d

>>> a.dtypes
id        int64
val     float64
type     object
dtype: object
>>> b.dtypes
id        int64
val     float64
type     object
dtype: object
```

It seems like it is dangerous to use 'float32/64' column types for alignment on on a join/merge operations due to rounding errors (significant digits). In the example above, file X had a value of 5.342 while file Y had 5.342**0**. How should I deal with this?

I tried doing set_option('precision', 4) before doing read_csv() but seems like this option is only for display.

Comment: you may try to round your DFs before joining...

Comment: Thanks. round() did the trick.